# Hide and visible a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a card on my website. I like it when the user hovers on the card, the card's brightness will be low and a little button appears on it. I used js "onmouseenter" to do that but it didn't work.

Comment: Use css `button-element:hover`

Comment: It didn't work the button always is visible

Comment: In HTML: <element onmouseover="yourjs">
In JavaScript: object.onmouseover = function(){yourjs};
Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: Please show your HTML/CSS so we can see what you are working with

Answer (score 3):

Use then `:hover` css tag as Itamar said

Ex:
css

```css
.card:hover .button {
    display: none;
}
```

hides button on hover

Comment: It didn't work. first, i set visibility to hidden and then I set it whit hover but it is always hidden when I hover on it id didn't be visible

Comment: refer i edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-class :hover

```
button:hover {
   {...}
};
```

Can you show us your CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const card = document.querySelector(`.card`);
const button = document.querySelector(`.button`);

card.addEventListener(`mouseenter`, () =>{  
  card.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(150,0,0)`;
  button.style.display = `block`;
});

card.addEventListener(`mouseleave`, () =>{  
  card.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(255,0,0)`;
  button.style.display = `none`;
});
```

```css
.card{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.button{
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <button class="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

I hope that this will help.